# RedirectTo, AmpScript and website-generated parameters

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, redirect, hyperlink

I have a URL that is created with some Ampscript that needs to have click-tracking.  However, there are parameters that our 3rd party's website adds and I believe that is breaking the link.

Here's the AmpScript I'm using to create the URL:

```
%%[
    var @Store_Id, @Store_Link, @RSTR_PLRS_First_Name, @SN_TMS_Name 
    SET @Store_Id = SL_Store_Id
    SET @Store_Link = Concat('https://teamlocker.squadlocker.com/#/lockers/', @Store_Id)
]%%

<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@store_link)=%%">Link</a>
```

So, when I go to test the link - this is what it's generating:
https://teamlocker.squadlocker.com/#/lockers/49753?cm_ven=ExactTarget&cm_cat=SE_SquadLockerTeamStore_Parent_Email1_jordan&cm_pla=All+Subscribers&cm_ite=STATIC+TEXT+HERE&cm_lm=nick.burggraf@sportsengine.com&cm_ainfo=&&&&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute4%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute5%%&_k=h94gl3

The final parameter **&_k=h94gl3** is generated from the webpage.
The webpage should render like this:   https://teamlocker.squadlocker.com/#/lockers/49753?_k=h94gl3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `&%%_AdditionalEmailAttributeX%%` breaks your links, you could raise a support case via the [Help & Training Portal](https://help.salesforce.com) to enable all available additional email attributes. Then you can set them in the properties of your emails. For every unset parameter just an ampersand is added to the url which shouldn't break the link. The other automatically added parameters like `cm_ven`, `cm_cat`, etc. shouldn't break your link either. You could also add an alias to your link, so this is set as `cm_ite` value.

Comment: Additional Attribute #4 and #5 were not enabled on our account.  Had to create a case and get those unlocked so they default parameters could be changed.  
  
This solved the problem.

Comment: @markus you know how many additional variables that can be configured?

Comment: @Data_Kid At the time I requested the activation of the additional fields, 5 was the maximum according to the support agent who worked on the case.