# When tracking clicks AMPscript tag breaks our landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

Newer user, so please ELI5 if you are able. I'm having a bit of a weird issue. When I have click tracking turned off my link my website works just fine. However, when I turn click tracking on the additional AMPscript code is added to the URL and the landing page won't fully load. My developers have said that having the %% characters is what's breaking the page. %25%25 is seems to work fine as well but the two characters next to each is what's causing the error. The tracking link that SFMC wraps it in breaks the link and the page doesn't load. The website is hosted off of Microsoft Azure too if that could cause anything.

Comment: Please can you provide a code example of the AMPscript code that you are using to build the href to the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your ampscript code, I can bet that you're having a similar problem that I had.

Check out this topic:
[RedirectTo, AmpScript and website-generated parameters](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180598/redirectto-ampscript-and-website-generated-parameters)

You need to use the RedirectTo function and find out whether or not SFMC is adding on extra parameters that are breaking your links when tracking.

Comment: Solved, that was it! Much appreciated.

Comment: @RKooshe make sure to mark it as the answer.  Glad I could help (through others helping)

Comment: @RKooshe Heads Up!  Personalization URLs like this are not trackable as an 'Engagement Split' within Journeys.    

Reference: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184335/journey-builder-engagement-splits-on-dynamic-links

Comment: have you tested the campaign yet or weren't able to select the links altogether? I was able to select the links on configuration settings within journey builder. I did a test campaign as well with the engagement split and everything seemed to be working ok. My links weren't dynamic though I built my UTM codes using [Google analytics code builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/)